# Django JSONField Aggregate and Sum

Tags: python, json, django, jsonb

I have the below JSON saved in PostgreSQL 9.4 DB and running Django 2.2

`[{"rating": 6, "companyvalue_id": 188, "team_members_name": "pidofod tester", "users_teammember_id": 2793}, {"rating": 7, "companyvalue_id": 207, "team_members_name": "pidofod tester", "users_teammember_id": 2793}, {"rating": 4, "companyvalue_id": 207, "team_members_name": "xakir tester", "users_teammember_id": 2795}]`

There is many database entries.

I would like to aggregate all instances of `team_members_name` and Sum to find out the total `rating`.

The JSON data is saved in a model field `data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)`

The closest I have is

```
def data_rating(self):
    model = apps.get_model('model', 'ModelName')
    model_count = model.objects.all()

    return model_count.objects.annotate(
        rating=Cast(
            KeyTextTransform("rating", "data"),
            IntegerField(),
        )
    ).values("rating").distinct().aggregate(Sum("rating"))["rating__sum"]
```

The above only works for single JSON object, i.e. `{"rating": 6, "companyvalue_id": 188, "team_members_name": "pidofod tester", "users_teammember_id": 2793}` however I need `KeyTextTransform` to work across many JSON objects and in many database rows.

I also need to filter/aggregate each user, i.e. what is `"team_members_name": "pidofod tester"`  total `rating` Sum.

End result is to return this result in a DRF endpoint.

Have tried many options as below but none work or seem close, feel a model re-work may be needed. Any ideas or suggestions appreciated!

```
    #return rating_tool_count.annotate(numbers_len=Func(F('rating_tool_data'), function='jsonb_array_length')).aggregate(rating_total=Sum(F("rating")))
    #return rating_tool_count.annotate(single_nested_value=F("rating_tool_data__team_members_name"),array_access=F("rating_tool_data__rating"),)

    #return rating_tool.objects.aggregate(Sum('rating_tool_data__rating')) #.values('rating_tool_data__rating').annotate(rating_total=Sum(Cast(KeyTextTransform("rating", "rating_tool_data"), models.IntegerField())))

    #return rating_tool_count.annotate(team_members_name=Cast(KeyTextTransform(
    #"team_members_name", "rating_tool_data"), models.TextField())).values("rating_tool_data").annotate(rating_total=Sum(Cast(KeyTextTransform("rating", "rating_tool_data"),
    #models.IntegerField())),).order_by("-rating_total")


    #return rating_tool_count.filter(rating_tool_data__name="pidofod tester").count()
    #return rating_tool_count.aggregate(Sum('rating_tool_data__rating'))
    #return rating_tool_count.aggregate(rating=Sum(Cast(KeyTextTransform("rating", "rating_tool_data"), models.IntegerField())))
    # return rating_tool_count.values('rating_tool_data__rating').annotate(rating_total=Sum('rating_tool_data__rating')).order_by('-rating_tool_data__rating')
    # return rating_tool_count.annotate(team_members_name=Cast(KeyTextTransform("team_members_name", "rating_tool_data"), models.TextField())).values("team_members_name").annotate(rating=Count("rating_tool_data"),ratings=Sum(Cast(KeyTextTransform("rating", "rating_tool_data"), models.IntegerField()))).order_by("-rating")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try postgresql jsonb instead of json

jsonb allow effisienty extract values in sql queries
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

also
https://pganalyze.com/blog/postgres-jsonb-django-python
can be usefull

Comment: Django JSONField is already jsonb